# How do I fix this weird cloth simul issue?

Tags: modeling, mesh, cloth-simulation, error

[image]

I tried following a tutorial where he says that after making a denser mesh he got his creases right, when I tried, I got it in a irregular place, I want it to go, any help appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: I am trying to achieve a effect as mentioned in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2iloupX7S8&t=1636s
at around 35:54, the folds that he get, I am trying to achieve just that, but somehow it's not working